# How to align a div tag (containing text) of unknown width to the right under another div tag

Tags: css

I have this input box that takes input and the text is appended inside a `<div>` called "parent" as another `<div>` called "child".

The code:

```js
const send = () => {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
  const text = document.querySelector('.text').value;
  const newtext = document.createElement("div");
  newtext.classList.add(".child");
  newtext.innerHTML = "Me: " + text;
  parent.appendChild(newtext);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 50%;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" class="text">
  <button onclick="send()">Send</button>
  <div class="parent"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to make the `<div>` with the class "child" appear on the right side. But the unknown width of the tag is making it hard to align with the `left` attribute in CSS. **How can I appear it on the right side each time a new text is published?**

Comment: do you mean you want each new .child side by sides ? or aside ok button and standing in a column ?

Comment: It's basically a chat app. So, my inbox here is the .parent and each text sent by me are the .child so I want the received messages to show on the left side of the .parent (which it is doing fine) and my sent messages on the right side of the .parent tag. So, I want sort of push the .child to the right inside the .parent tag. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do here...

Comment: text-align should do with flex https://jsfiddle.net/cqsh3Lv5/ or on its own https://jsfiddle.net/eqa2760z/

Comment: hmmm just realized you add that child class supposed to be applied , so , grid & margin can easily help. added bg too https://jsfiddle.net/6g35uwz2/ Can you clarify from here what you need ?

Comment: here is the idea https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYxMERJ .. going off line.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float: right` (and `clear: both;`  in order to always position it *below*  the previous entry)

BTW: I would also use `display: inline-block` for it to allow it to be as narrow as its contents, and erase those "fit-content" settings.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function send () {
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.parent{
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.child{
  width: 50%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" class="text">
<button onclick="send()">Send</button>
<div class="parent"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't create any new tag anymore, and each click resets content. not sure that was the intend of the op ;)

Answer (score 0):

The width of parent is set as 100% - 100% of what? In the structure given it is 100% of the body. body has been given no explicit width so it takes up the width of what is in it, which is the input element.

Also, there is a typo in the adding to the classList, the dot should not be there on .child.

So, it's a question of what do you want the width of parent to be at any time?
In this snippet nothing is done to change what is there now in terms of its (intrinsic) width but child is positioned to the right hand side, ie it aligns on the right to the end of the submit button.

If you meant parent to fill the whole viewport then set the body with to 100vw.

```js
const send = () => {
    const parent=document.querySelector('.parent');
    const text=document.querySelector('.text').value;
    const newtext = document.createElement("div");
    newtext.classList.add("child");
    newtext.innerHTML = "Me: "+text;
    parent.appendChild(newtext);
    }
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    body{
    position: absolute;
    rwidth: 100vw;
    }
    .parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .child{
    position: relative;
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    text-align: right;
    max-width: 50%;
    white-space: pre-line;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" class="text">
    <button onclick="send()">Send</button>
    <div class="parent"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```